# Robocopy MINAGE/MAXAGE

Tags: windows, scripting, robocopy

I'm trying to run the robocopy command to copy all files that have not been accessed in 3 years to another location.

The path is s:\share\tech one and the destination is s:\share\hold

I seem to be missing a piece, for some reason I can't get the files to show up in the folder. And that's just using a MINAGE/MAXAGE switch.

Could someone show me the proper syntax?

Comment: Modern versions of Windows do not update the last access date by default.  You can check the configuration of your system with the `fsutil behavior query disablelastaccess` command.

Answer (score 0):

This is the switch you need (looking in Win 8.1 version of Robocopy):

```
/MINLAD:1095
```

`LAD` is last access date

Comment: It's only copying one file though. There are many more files, it's only copying thumbs.db.

Comment: Note Harry Johnston's comment to your question.